# SQL select query to retrieve an image

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

Amongst the various informati require, I would like to use the query below on the on load event of a form to return to three immages (photos). I am not sure if this is possible.  When loading the form where there photos are suppose to appear i am getting the following symbol in the place of the foto:
 ᰕ/

Is it possible that what i am trying to do is not possible?

```
            Private Sub Form_Load()
        sql_get = "SELECT tblTeamsDivision.Division, 
        tblContacts.CompleteName AS DivisionLead, 
        tblContacts.Foto AS DivLeadFoto, 
        tblTeamsDepartments.Department, 
        tblContacts_1.CompleteName AS DeptLead, 
        tblContacts_1.Foto AS DeptLeadFoto, 
        tblTeams.Team, tblContacts_2.CompleteName AS TeamLead, 
        tblContacts_2.Foto AS TeamLeadFoto FROM tblContacts 
        AS tblContacts_2 INNER JOIN 
        (tblTeams INNER JOIN (tblContacts AS tblContacts_1 
        INNER JOIN (tblContacts INNER JOIN (tblTeamsDivision 
    INNER JOIN tblTeamsDepartments ON tblTeamsDivision.number = tblTeamsDepartments.Division) 
    ON tblContacts.ID = tblTeamsDivision.DivisionLead) 
    ON tblContacts_1.ID = tblTeamsDepartments.Dept_Head) 
ON tblTeams.Department = tblTeamsDepartments.ID) ON tblContacts_2.ID = tblTeams.Supervisor"
    Form_frmStaticDataSkills01.Form.RecordSource = sql_get

            End Sub
```

Comment: whats the column datatype where photo is stored? is it stored in ms-saccess

Comment: Yes it is stored in MS access. It is an ole object

Comment: is it possible to change ole from BLOB?

Comment: I am not sure.. What is BLOB..??

Comment: I don't use Access very often, but I read that when you use an OLE Object field, Access appends a bunch of header information to the byte array before storing it. So, in this case, you would need to strip out this junk before returning the contents.